# How to access property inside function constructor javascript

Tags: javascript

I need to manipulate HTML tags through a class as such:

```
/*
 * Begin: HTML Class
 */
HTML = function(el, property) { // Construct
    this.el = el;
    this.property = new Array;
    var HTML = document.createElement(el);

    this.element = function() {
        return HTML;
    };

    HTML.objects.push(this);

    if (typeof property == "object")
        for (i in property)
            this.addProperty(i, property[i]);
};

HTML.objects = new Array; // Registers all new HTML objects.

// Adds a new property to HTML current element.
HTML.prototype.addProperty = function(name, value) {
    this.property[name] = value;
    this.getHTML()[name] = value;
};

// Retrieves current HTML element.
HTML.prototype.getHTML = function() {
    return this.element();
};

// Clones current HTML objects with same construct arguments.
HTML.prototype.clone = function() {
    return new HTML(this.el, this.property);
};
/*
 * End: HTML Class
 */
```

Each time `new HTML(...)` is called, newly created instance must be stored within `HTML.objects` which is a static property of HTML whose role is to keep track of all HTML objects. But now when it reaches to `HTML.objects.push(this);` it will return undefined property error. After, I tried to call for `HTML.objects` in firebug and it was definitely defined. As `function(...) { ... }` is called at instantiation, shouldn't it be able to access `HTML.objects` property?
Thanks.

Comment: I would strongly recommend to resolve the name clash between `HTML` and `HTML`.

Comment: Also `HTML` is a particularly bad name for a *DOM* *element* (which has nothing to do with HTML markup). Some goes for the `.getHTML()` method - just use the `.element()` one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The proprety `HTML.objects` doesn't exists because in your constructor's scope `HTML` is the variable you have defined here:

```
var HTML = document.createElement(el);
```

so, when you make this call:

```
HTML.objects.push(this);
```

you are trying to access the proprey of the just declared `HTML` variable.

In fact, if you try to replace the first line with:

```
var HTML_INNER = document.createElement(el);
```

It'll work

Comment: WOW ! Now I feel shameful. I was testing it with another object which was working fine. But in the other object I was not defining an internal var with same name as object. Thanks a lot.

Comment: :) another advice is: you use the same name 'property' for a constructor parameter and a object field, but you don't assign the parameter to the field in the constructor. This could lead to misunderstandings